# Remove rounded corner for uiviewcontroller's view ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have to remove round corner from `UIView` of `UIViewcontroller`. here is the image for that [image]

I am presenting detail view with

```
detailView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
```

I want to present `UIViewcontroller` without rounded corner of view.
Anyone have idea for this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
//You will have to link to the QuartzCore library
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //set border radius on visibility
    self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 0;
}

- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation 
{
    //for some reason the cornerRadius resets itself on orientation change
    self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 0;
 }
```

self.view can be view inside the ViewController which you are presenting.

Comment: Thank you for answering Bhargavi I have tried it but not written in didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation method. Relay appreciated answer.

Comment: Great answer - however you should include a call to the superclass ([super viewWillAppear:animated];) or things like automatic row deselection in UITableViewControllers will stop working.

Comment: @GrahamPerks yes I agree with your suggestion. But I just wanted to show where to write that 'cornerRadius'.

Comment: In my case I had to use `self.view.superview.layer.cornerRadius = 0`