# Remove rounded corner of modal uinavigationcontroller

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I'm presenting a UINavigationController modally.

```
_navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
```

I want to show the modal controller with rounded corners. I tried this: [Remove rounded corner for uiviewcontroller's view ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977120/remove-rounded-corner-for-uiviewcontrollers-view-ipad)

It's working fine with UIViewControllers. 
For UINavigationController, I tried setting corner radius of navigation controller's view to 0. Also set corner radius of UIViews of all the UIViewControllers inside the UINavigationController. But nothing is working.

Anyone have any idea how to do it??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**VC.m**

```
 #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Navigationbar without corner"];

    self.navigationController.view.layer.cornerRadius = 0;
}
```

Here is the result for above code

[image]

Comment: I need to do the change in the superview to make it work. self.navigationController.view.superview.layer.cornerRadius = 0;